# Vuepress: get sidebar to work in a single page

Tags: vuejs2, markdown, vuepress

I created a really simple vuepress project with the following folder tree:

```
| README.md
| .vuepress
 -- config.js
| package.json
```

My `README.md` has some markdown headings with `#` symbols and some text.

I just want to get a sidebar in the left with links to the headings.

In order to do so, I setup the `config.js` as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  title: 'title',
  description: 'description',
  themeConfig: {
    sidebar: 'auto',
  },
}
```

Also, in the readme page I have a metadata section at the beginning with the following:

```
---
home: true
---
```

Thee page is clearly getting the [default theme](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/default-theme-config) styles and behavior, if I add other main theme stuff like `features` it works as expected.

However, there is no sidebar with links in the left.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a page marked as homepage via metadata cannot render a sidebar. In order to get `sidebar: auto` to work, I needed to create another readme page inside a dedicated folder, like:

```
| README.md
| .vuepress/
 -- config.js
| package.json
| docs/
 -- README.md
```

Then, the `/docs/` route displays a page with the sidebar properly formatted.